# Strange behavior when using jQuery UI progress bar and ajax with Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsp, google-chrome, progress-bar

Recently I am trying the jQuery UI progress bar with ajax for building a file upload progress bar.

It works like charm in IE and firefox, but the behavior in Chrome is very weird, which makes me think I have done something wrong in the coding part.

My design is to loop the ajax function to retrieve the upload bytes read from a servlet, and it works in IE and firefox.

However, when running in Chrome, the ajax function can only retrieve the upload bytes read one time only, aka the loop only success for the first time.

[image]

At the bottom left corner of the Chrome browser, the upload percent counter shows the upload is still running, which makes me think the problem is related to the ajax call.

I have tried to print the error message from ajax, but turns out there is no error message.

[image]

Please find below my source codes:

ajax:

```
       function doProgressLoop() {
            setTimeout("getProgress()", 1500);
            setTimeout("doProgressLoop()", 2000);
        }

        function getProgress() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/processUpload",
                dataType: "text",
                data: "",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data != "null" && parseInt(data) < 100) {
                        progressbar.progressbar("value", parseInt(data));
                    }
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                    console.log(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        function fSubmit() {
            jQuery("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            progressbar.show();
            doProgressLoop();
            setTimeout("jQuery('#hiddenSubmit').click()", 2000);
        }
```

Servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        if (session == null) {
            System.out.println("HTTPSession is null");
            out.println("HTTPSession: null");
            return;
        }

        ProgressEntity entity = (ProgressEntity) session.getAttribute("upload_file");

        if(entity == null) {
            logger.info("entity is null");
            out.println("null");
        } else {
            logger.info("entity: " + entity.getPercentDone());
            out.println(String.valueOf(entity.getPercentDone()));
        }

    }
```

ProgressListener:

```
public class UploadProgressListener implements ProgressListener {

private HttpSession session;
private int percentDone = 0;
private long bytesRead;
private long contentLength;
private int items;

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadProgressListener.class);

public UploadProgressListener(HttpSession session) {
    this.session = session;
    ProgressEntity entity = new ProgressEntity();
    session.setAttribute("upload_file", entity);
}

public void update(long bytesRead, long contentLength, int items) {

    ProgressEntity entity = (ProgressEntity) session.getAttribute("upload_file");

    entity.setBytesRead(bytesRead);
    entity.setContentLength(contentLength);
    entity.setItems(items);

    session.setAttribute("upload_file", entity);

    this.bytesRead = bytesRead;
    this.contentLength = contentLength;
    this.items = items;

}

public long getBytesRead() {
    return this.bytesRead;
}

}
```

MultipartResolver:

```
public class ProgressUploadMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

private HttpServletRequest request;
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProgressUploadMultipartResolver.class);

protected FileUpload newFileUpload(FileItemFactory fileItemFactory) {

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
    upload.setSizeMax(-1);

    if(request != null) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        UploadProgressListener uploadProgressListener = new UploadProgressListener(session);
        upload.setProgressListener(uploadProgressListener);
    }

    return upload;
}

@Override
public MultipartHttpServletRequest resolveMultipart (HttpServletRequest request) throws MultipartException {
    this.request = request;
    return super.resolveMultipart(request);
}

@Override
public MultipartParsingResult parseRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws MultipartException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    String encoding = "utf-8";
    FileUpload fileUpload = prepareFileUpload(encoding);

    UploadProgressListener uploadProgressListener = new UploadProgressListener(session);
    fileUpload.setProgressListener(uploadProgressListener);
    try {

        List<FileItem> fileItems = ((ServletFileUpload) fileUpload).parseRequest(request);
        return parseFileItems(fileItems, encoding);

    } catch(FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Progress Info:

```
public class ProgressEntity {

private long bytesRead = 0L;
private long contentLength = 0L;
private int items;

public long getBytesRead() {
    return bytesRead;
}
public void setBytesRead(long bytesRead) {
    this.bytesRead = bytesRead;
}
public long getContentLength() {
    return contentLength;
}
public void setContentLength(long contentLength) {
    this.contentLength = contentLength;
}
public int getItems() {
    return items;
}
public void setItems(int items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

}

Please let me know if you need me to provide any more source code.

Thank you very much!

***Update:***

Please find above the Javascript functions for progress bar.

fSubmit() function will be called when the submit button is clicked.

***Update2:***

Others java codes are added as well.

Comment: Where is the code for loop?

Answer (score 0):

As no one can suggest a suitable answer (maybe my question is too weird??),

here I would like to answer my own question on how I finally get it done,

so that if anyone encounter similar issue, they will have one possible solution to try out.

The answer is very simple,

I create an iframe in the jsp, and set the target of the form to that iframe,

then the progress bar in Chrome works like charm.

I am really too new to the field of ajax and jQuery so I don't know why just an iframe will solve this problem which bother me for a week......

Although I have to deal with another problem since the end point jsp is now showing inside the iframe instead of the parent page, at least the progress bar is working across all common browsers, and the redirect issue is another mystery to solve for tomorrow......

Anyway hope anyone encounter this issue can try out this method, wish you good luck.